# Js Function Calling with another way

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that fills an array...
I want to use it like this `arrayname.fill("First Array");`
But not like this `arrayname = fill("First Array");`
How can I accomplish this?

```
function fill(name)
{
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        array[i] = prompt(name + "\nFill it");
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Your function creates a *new* array with three elements and returns it. How do you expect it to work if you call it as a method on an existing array - should it just do 3 elements as in your function, or overwrite all existing elements, or...? Also, I wouldn't recommend adding a method called `.fill()` to the array prototype given that JavaScript arrays already have a [built in `.fill()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) (and your function doesn't work the same way).

Comment: Can I ask why you need to use it that way? And as @nnnnnn points out, JS already has a `.fill()` which will be overwritten by your function, this is likely to break anywhere else in your script where the standard `.fill()` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.fill = function fill(name)
{
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        array[i] = prompt(name + "\nFill it");
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you must add your function to the prototype of the `Array` Object (but it's not recommended) :

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(name) {
  var array = [];
      for(var i = 0;i < 3;i++) {
        array[i] = prompt(name + "\nFill it");
      }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(name) {
      for(var i = 0;i < 3;i++) 
      {
        this[i] = prompt(name + "\nFill it");
      }
  return this;
}
```

I'm just changed array name to this... and removed line `var array = [];`

After Doing it all running how i need , thank you all!!!